# How can we use <script> and <link> tag in md-dialog template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, materialize, angularjs-material

I have a md-dialog box code is below

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function (ev, category, finalStep, currentStep) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogEventController,
      templateUrl: '/app/modules/event/eventCreationSteps.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: false,
      fullscreen: true,
      locals: {
        category: category,
        finalStep: finalStep,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        storage: null,
      }
    })
  };
```

and in this '/app/modules/event/eventCreationSteps.html' file i wants to create a text area with html editor functionality, and that is using some external Js and css files, code is below

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <link href="/assets/css/info.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/widgContent.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/widgEditor.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/app/../assets/js/widgEditor.js"></script>
    <textarea name="noise" class="widgEditor nothing">Text something</textarea>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

this code is working at other place but not in eventCreationSteps.html file

Comment: that would be a MVC violation. you are not supposed to add script tags into views.

Comment: I understand its MVC violation, just to showcase my problem I kept that code there, that is the scenario, what could be the solutions for this?

Comment: @SikandarYadav, you can add these scripts in the index.html or add them to `script` attribute in `.angular-cli.json`. Then You can use these JS files (as in you can use `variables` exported by these scripts).

Comment: well. if you understand it's mvc violation then just follow what mvc is guidelining and either include it in your main or let the script be inserted by the controller asyncronously before you are using it. this way you could lazily load it. that would still be a hack but would do the job.